# smartface apps with ios 9 crashing need to update apps?

Tags: smartface.io

The apps published with smartface are crashing with new ios 9 operating system. Does it need to update the published apps with latest version or not?

Answer (score 0):

Alex, you should update to latest version, you can download it directly from our WebSite. 
The latest version includes iOS9 support.